# understanding Macros in C and preprocessor directives

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I don't understand those macros, how does it work?, also what is irc_##name ?..i've got this code from insobot IRC bot,here is the code https://github.com/baines/insobot/blob/master/src/insobot.c

```
#define IRC_CALLBACK_BASE(name, event_type) static void irc_##name ( \
irc_session_t* session, \
event_type     event,   \
const char*    origin,  \
const char**   params,  \
unsigned int   count    \
)

#define IRC_STR_CALLBACK(name) IRC_CALLBACK_BASE(name, const char*)
#define IRC_NUM_CALLBACK(name) IRC_CALLBACK_BASE(name, unsigned int)
```

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: This is basic preprocessor usage. Please read some online C tutorials or a book about C: for example "The C programming language" by Ritchie and Kernighan.

Comment: And what specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: It is basic C grammar. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`##` is the token concatenation operator: it is used in these macro definitions to create the identifier for the name of the callback function by prepending `irc_` before the value of the first argument of the macro `IRC_STR_CALLBACK` and/or `IRC_NUM_CALLBACK`

Look at this macro invocation at line 183:

```
IRC_STR_CALLBACK(on_join);
```

this source line gets expanded to

```
static void irc_on_join ( irc_session_t* session, event_type     event,   const char*    origin,  const char**   params,  unsigned int   count    );
```

The macro is used to declare the handler in a consistent fashion without the need to write the prototype explicitly, which is handy because there are many handlers in this source file.